# SQL Multiple CASE statements return 0 instead of NULL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I Have the following SQL Case statement which works perfectly as long as the Years match `MF.Date & M.MemberCurrentYear`. There will be scenarios where the years do not match and this returns a Balance of *`NULL`*. I would like it to return a Zero.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Amount ELSE Amount * - 1 END) AS Balance
FROM dbo.MemberFinancials AS MF 
INNER JOIN dbo.Members AS M ON MF.MemberID = M.MemberID 
  AND DATEPART(yyyy, MF.Date) = M.MemberCurrentYear 
INNER JOIN dbo.FinancialTypes AS FT ON MF.FinancialTypeID = FT.FinancialTypeID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT     

     ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Amount ELSE Amount * - 1 END),0) AS Balance
FROM         dbo.MemberFinancials AS MF INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Members AS M ON MF.MemberID = M.MemberID AND DATEPART(yyyy, MF.Date) = M.MemberCurrentYear INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FinancialTypes AS FT ON MF.FinancialTypeID = FT.FinancialTypeID
```

Use ISNULL (Or COALESCE if you prefer...)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ISNULL( SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Amount ELSE Amount * - 1 END), 0) AS Balance
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Amount ELSE Amount * - 1 END)
    , 0) AS Balance
```